# yield return versus return select

Tags: c#, .net, linq, select, yield

Which are the advantages/drawbacks of both approaches?

```
return items.Select(item => DoSomething(item));
```

versus

```
foreach(var item in items)
{
    yield return DoSomething(item);
}
```

**EDIT** As they are MSIL roughly equivalent, which one you find more readable?

Comment: Your second code fragment is the *implementation* of Select. (Assuming this is LINQ to Objects.)  That's all Select does -- it runs a foreach loop, runs the delegate on each item, and yields the results.

Comment: yep. But there is still differences when typing the first and the second. 1st difference : number of LOCs, 2nd difference: readability, 3rd difference: when yield return is present in a method, some restrictions apply (ie: you can't put return select after yield return in the same method).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `yield return` technique causes the C# compiler to generate an enumerator class "behind the scenes", while the `Select` call uses a standard enumerator class parameterized with a delegate.  In practice, there shouldn't be a whole lot of difference between the two, other than possibly an extra call frame in the `Select` case, for the delegate.

For what it's worth, wrapping a lambda around `DoSomething` is sort of pointless as well; just pass a delegate for it directly.

Comment: What's going to be different from passing a delegate, as opposed to the lambda, in this case?

Comment: return items.Select(DoSomething);

Comment: Ah, like that, didn't think of that.

Answer (score 13):

In the slow-moving corporate world where I currently spend more time than I'd wish, yield return has the enormous advantage that it doesn't need that brand new .NET 3.5 Framework that won't be installed for at least another 2 years.

Comment: Cool answer. But .NET Framework 3.5 is being updated soon (4.0).

Comment: ".NET Framework 3.5 is being updated soon" - Not where I work :(

Answer (score 5):

Select only allows you to return one object for each item in your "items" collection.
Using an additional `.Where(x => DoIReallyWantThis(x))` allows you to weed out unwanted items, but still only allows you to return one object per item.
If you want potentially more than one object per item, you can use `.SelectMany` but it is easy to wind up with a single long line that is less than easy to read.

"yield return" has the potential to make your code more readable if you are looking through a complex data structure and picking out bits of information here and there. The best example of this that I have seen was where there were around a dozen separate conditions which would result in a returned object, and in each case the returned object was constructed differently.